# Pros and cons of Datameer vs Altreyx

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, analytics

I am trying to evaluate Datameer and Altreyx for our bigdata analytics needs. What are the pros and cons of these two tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, full disclosure: I am Sr. Director for Technical Product Marketing at Datameer, so treat what I have to say with appropriate skepticism.  For what it's worth, I also write about Big Data (but not about Datameer) for ZDNet, and I was Research Director for Big Data and Analytics at Gigaom Research.  So I know a thing or two about the BI/Big Data market.

With that out of the way, let me say that Alteryx and Datameer are actually rather different products.  Even if our messaging may sound similar at times, we do different things.

Alteryx does a great job of allowing its users to set up workflows, graphically, for data transformation, then run those workflows when the design is done.  Alteryx connects to Hadoop via Hive and its ODBC driver, moving data out of Hadoop in order to process it.

Alteryx runs as a Windows desktop application, using a UI that looks much like an Integrated Development Environment (IDE).  If you're a developer, or even a certain type of power user (for example, one who likes to write a little code now and then), you'll be right at home.

Datameer, on the other hand, can run on Hadoop natively.  Instead of connecting via Hive and moving data from Hadoop into our engine, Hadoop in fact *is* our engine, where that makes the most sense.  Rather than graphical workflows, we use a spreadsheet metaphor, allowing users to enter formulas in sheets in order to effect data transformation/shaping/cleansing.  And instead of making you execute your whole workbook to see results, our Smart Sampling feature brings data in at design time, so you can work interactively with a subset of the data before you decide to execute the full workbook from end-to-end.

Datameer runs in a Web browser, not as a desktop application, allowing us to run cross-platform between Windows and Mac OS (for example), as well as on tablets running Android, iOS or Windows.  Datameer can run on-prem or as a service, in various configurations.  With our Personal and Workgroup products, with which you'd likely be processing smaller data volumes, we bypass Hadoop and execute your workbook in-memory.

We have premium modules that do some interesting things.  Smart Execution can simplify some Hadoop decisions you'd otherwise have to make on your own, including whether to use MapReduce, Tez or our local in-memory engine.  Our Smart Analytics module lets you use machine learning algorithms to understand your data better, and we make pretty short work of doing so.

Alteryx essentially wraps R to deliver machine learning services, and does so for predictive analytics, rather than for data discovery, per se.  The ML capabilities in Alteryx are more comprehensive than ours, but they are based on R functions inserted into data flows whereas our ML feature is Wizard-driven.  Our ML feature set is smaller and, we believe, simpler.  The 80-20 rule applies, from our point of view.

Alteryx does an excellent job of integrating consumer and spatial data to calculate and visualize things like locations within a certain drive-time radius.  Datameer does not have a comparable feature.  On the other hand, we do have over 60 native connectors to various RDBMS, DW, NoSQL, social and SaaS databases and services, and they come in the box.  The datasets that Alteryx can integrate with come at relatively high cost, per seat, at least in terms of list prices on the company's site (at http://www.alteryx.com/products/pricing).

Alteryx is BI product with a rich heritage dating back a decade, and the company has done a good job of adding Big Data features as those have become relevant to the market.  Datameer was designed from scratch around Big Data use cases and technologies.  So, really, we are very different.  Can you do the same sorts of things with the two products?  Sure.  You can also do the same sorts of things with Excel macros and coding in C; that's just how computation works.  But our approaches are rather different.